# Clipping a raster with a multipolygon using rasterio in Python

Tags: python, geojson, clip, rasterio

I'm trying to write a function to clip rasters by a multi-polygon shapefile or GeoJSON in Python using rasterio.

So far, I found a [good article](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/clipping-raster.html) that I've implemented, but it doesn't seem to work on clipping all polygons within a multi-polygon layer. Perhaps it is in this function below that prepares the GeoDataFrame for use in rasterio, which seems to only take the first feature geometry?

```
def getFeatures(gdf):
    """Function to parse features from GeoDataFrame in such a manner that rasterio wants them"""
    import json
    return [json.loads(gdf.to_json())['features'][0]['geometry']]
```

How would I clip a raster using a multi-polygon GeoJSON or shapefile in Python using rasterio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I used this [example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html) integrated with a `for loop`.

Note that `rasterio.mask.mask(src, shape, crop=True)` needs to be changed to `[shape]` due to [shapes (iterable object) – The values must be a GeoJSON-like dict or an object that implements the Python geo interface protocol (such as a Shapely Polygon)](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.mask.html).

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import fiona


shapefile = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/grid.shp"
image = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/image.tif"


def rasterio_clip(shapefile_path, raster_path):
    with fiona.open(shapefile_path, "r") as shapefile:
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

    for i, shape in enumerate(shapes):
        with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
            out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [shape], crop=True)
            out_meta = src.meta

        out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                    "height": out_image.shape[1],
                    "width": out_image.shape[2],
                    "transform": out_transform})

        with rasterio.open(f"C:/Users/user/Desktop/CLIPPED/clipped_{i}.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(out_image)

rasterio_clip(shapefile, image)
```

[image]